# Jsonデータの持ち回りと値の受け渡しについて

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax, thymeleaf

#### 前提・実現したいこと

我ながらお恥ずかしい話ですが、APIから取得するデータでツリー表示をさせ、画面上にデータとして残すようなページをサンプルで作っています。
どうか皆様のアドバイス（ソースコード）などのお力添えをお願いいたします。
環境等は最下部に記載しています。
以下が実現したいことです。

Jsonデータ　⇒　取得してツリー表示（初期表示）　⇒ ツリー内のボタン（プラスボタンなど）　⇒対象のJsonデータを再度取得　⇒ 取得したデータを画面上の任意の箇所に表示ボタンが押された場合にのみ表示

#### イメージ

```
-書店
　- BOOK
　　　ワンピース☑️
＋ホテル
＋電気
＋八百屋


　 　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　表示ボタン


表示場所[ワンピース]
```

チェック箇所の情報をHTML(thymeleaf)内の任意の場所に表示する。
表示内容はイメージのとこにあるワンピースという名称でページ数などは裏で結びついて持っていきたい。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

AjaxとJavaでの連携でJsonを取得して、ツリー表示できない。
実現できるなら、AjaxでもJavaでもどちらでもいいのですが、Jsonをツリー表示するのがわからなく、プラスボタンで再度Jsonデータを呼びに行く方法がわからないという現状です。

#### 該当のソースコード

**Java**

```
@Service
public class ZipCodeService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("zipCodeSearchRestTemplate")
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    /** サンプル検索API リクエストURL */
    private static final String URL = "http://zipcloud.ibsnet.co.jp/api/search?zipcode={zipcode}";

    public ZipCodeDto service(String zipcode) {
        return restTemplate.getForObject(URL, ZipCodeDto.class, zipcode);
    }

}
```

**java**

```
@Controller
public class ZipCodeController {

    @Autowired
    ZipCodeService zpcService;

    /**
     * サンプル入力フォーム
     * @return "zipcode"
     */
    @RequestMapping("/zipcode")
    public String zipcodeForm(HttpSession session, Model model) {
        return "zipcode";
    }

    /**
     * サンプル情報表示 
     * @return "zipcode-confirm"
     */
    @RequestMapping(value="/zipcode/confirm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String zipcodeConfirm(HttpSession session, Model model, 
                                 @RequestParam("zipcode") String zipcode){

        // 一応必須チェックのみ 数字・桁数チェックは省略
        // nullまたは空文字の場合、入力フォームにエラーメッセージを表示
        if (zipcode == null || zipcode.equals("")) {
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage", "郵便番号を入力してください。");
            return zipcodeForm(session, model);
        }

        // サンプル検索APIサービス呼び出し
        ZipCodeDto zipCodeDto = zpcService.service(zipcode);
        // thymeleafでリストを展開して表示する
        model.addAttribute("zipcodeList", zipCodeDto.getResults());
        return "zipcode-confirm";   
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
        <title>設置サンプル</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/content/lib/yui/build/treeview/treeview.css?_yuiversion=2.4.1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/content/lib/yui/build/treeview/tree.css?_yuiversion=2.4.1" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/lib/yui/build/yahoo/yahoo.js?_yuiversion=2.4.1"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/lib/yui/build/event/event.js?_yuiversion=2.4.1"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/lib/yui/build/treeview/treeview.js?_yuiversion=2.4.1"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
                margin:0; padding:0;
            }
            body{
                margin:0 auto; padding:0;
                background-color:#666;
                color:#666;
                font:81%/1.5 verdana,sans-serif;
                text-align:center;
            }
            #wrap {
                width:500px;
                margin:0 auto; padding:0;
                background-color:#fff;
                text-align:center;
            }
            #content {
                margin:0 20px; padding:0;
                text-align:left;
            }
            #footer {
                margin:1em 0 0 0; padding:.2em .5em;
                background-color:#999;
                color:#fff;
                font-size:78%;
                text-align:right;
            }
            #footer * {
                font-style:normal;
                font-size:100%;
                color:#fff;
            }
            h1 {
                margin:0 0 1em 0; padding:.5em 1em;
                background-color:#999;
                color:#fff;
                font-size:100%;
                text-align:left;
            }
            h1 a {
                color:#fff;
            }
            p {
                margin:1em 0; padding:0;
            }
            img {
                border:0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <h1>設置サンプル</h1>
            <p>参照：<a href="http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/treeview/folder_style.html">YUI Library &raquo; Tree View Control &raquo; Folder-Style TreeView Design</a></p>
            <div id="content">
                <p>
                    <a id="expand" href="#">Expand all</a> | 
                    <a id="collapse" href="#">Collapse all</a>
                </p>
                <div id="treeDiv1"></div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                //an anonymous function wraps our code to keep our variables
                //in function scope rather than in the global namespace:
                (function() {
                    var tree; //will hold our TreeView instance
                    function treeInit() {
                        YAHOO.log("Example's treeInit function firing.", "info", "example");
                        //Hand off ot a method that randomly generates tree nodes:
                        buildRandomTextNodeTree();
                        //handler for expanding all nodes
                        YAHOO.util.Event.on("expand", "click", function(e) {
                            YAHOO.log("Expanding all TreeView  nodes.", "info", "example");
                            tree.expandAll();
                            YAHOO.util.Event.preventDefault(e);
                        });
                        //handler for collapsing all nodes
                        YAHOO.util.Event.on("collapse", "click", function(e) {
                            YAHOO.log("Collapsing all TreeView  nodes.", "info", "example");
                            tree.collapseAll();
                            YAHOO.util.Event.preventDefault(e);
                        });
                    }
                    //This method will build a TreeView instance and populate it with
                    //between 3 and 7 top-level nodes
                    function buildRandomTextNodeTree() {
                        //instantiate the tree:
                        tree = new YAHOO.widget.TreeView("treeDiv1");

                        //create top-level nodes
                        for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((Math.random()*4) + 3); i++) {
                            var tmpNode = new YAHOO.widget.TextNode("label-" + i, tree.getRoot(), false);

                            //we'll delegate to another function to build child nodes:
                            buildRandomTextBranch(tmpNode);
                        }
                        //once it's all built out, we need to render
                        //our TreeView instance:
                        tree.draw();
                    }
                    //This function adds a random number <4 of child nodes to a given
                    //node, stopping at a specific node depth:
                    function buildRandomTextBranch(node) {
                        if (node.depth < 6) {
                            YAHOO.log("buildRandomTextBranch: " + node.index);
                            for ( var i = 0; i < Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) ; i++ ) {
                                var tmpNode = new YAHOO.widget.TextNode(node.label + "-" + i, node, false);
                                buildRandomTextBranch(tmpNode);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //When the DOM is done loading, we can initialize our TreeView
                    //instance:
                    YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(treeInit);
                })();//anonymous function wrapper closed; () notation executes function
                </script>
            </div><!-- div#wrap/div#content -->
        </div><!-- div#wrap -->
    </body>
</html>
```

**js**

```
jQuery( function() {
    jQuery( '#jquery-sample-button' ) . toggle(
        function() {
            jQuery . ajax( {
                url: 'jquery-sample-ajax-json.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    year: '2011',
                    month: '11',
                    day: '25'
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    jQuery . each( data, function( key, value ) {
                        jQuery( '#jquery-sample-ajax' ) . append( '<p>' + key + ': ' + value + '</p>' );
                    } );
                    jQuery( '#jquery-sample-textStatus' ) . text( '読み込み成功' );
                },
                error: function( data ) {
                    jQuery( '#jquery-sample-textStatus' ) . text( '読み込み失敗' );
                }
            } );
        },
        function() {
            jQuery( '#jquery-sample-ajax' ) . html( '' );
            jQuery( '#jquery-sample-textStatus' ) . text( '' );
        }
    );
} );
```

#### 対象のJSONデータ

**Json**

```
{
 "book1":{
"title": "Book",
 "year": 2005 ,
"page": 399
},
"book2":{
 "title": "ワンピース",
 "year": 2006 ,
"page": 650
 }
}
```

#### 補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど)

STS、SpringBoot、Java8,Javascript、HTML、Timeleaf

Comment: マルチポスト　https://qiita.com/Grand-Place/items/f5a76d0e9a349624bcce